# How many possible states does the 8-puzzle have?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, sliding-tile-puzzle

The classical 8-puzzle belongs to the family of sliding blocks. My book (Artificial intelligence A modern approach by Stuart Russell and peter Norwig) says that the 8-puzzle has **9!/2** possible states. But WHY the ***/2*** ? How do you get this?

Comment: There is an [explanation on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`9!` is the total number of possible configurations of the puzzle, whereas `9!/2` is the total number of *solvable* configurations. For example, this configuration doesn't have a solution:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
8 7
```

Read more about the solvability of certain configurations of the n-puzzle in this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle#Solvability), or as pointed out by @dasblinkenlight in this MathWorld [explanation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html).

One possible way to find out that `9!/2` is the number of solvable configurations is to start from a solved puzzle and generate all the possible valid, non-repeating movements from it.

Comment: While this might be correct, it is not (yet) an explanation for why we have to divide by 2. Or is it?

Comment: So how does the fact that some configurations aren't possible cause us to divide it by 2?

Comment: The simple explanation is that **exactly half** the configurations aren't possible to reach from any chosen starting point (or alternately, can't reach any randomly chosen ending point), so we divide total configurations (9!) by 2 to get the total number of states that can move step by step to the solution. If you want to know _why_ exactly half cannot be reached you will need to learn about "parity". A reasonable starting point is http://www.jimloy.com/puzz/15.htm

Comment: If you draw a graph of every single state with every single possible transition out of that state you will end up with 9! / 2 states with 9! transitions. There are states that exist but don't fall on the graph and those are the "unsolvable" ones. It just happens that it's half of 9!.

Comment: I would quibble with the first sentence. We may be able to _place_ 8 blocks on 9 spaces in 9! configurations, but there are only 9!/2 reachable configurations of this sliding puzzle.